# DNS from VPN blocks local websites

Tags: windows, windows-10, vpn, dns, remote-desktop

I've got to use a PPTP VPN to connect to my work's desktop pc via RDP.

Over there certain sites are blocked, as I understand, by the DNS. Eg: If I try to access a music streaming site on Firefox, it shows an OpenDNS screen with a message saying something like "This site has been blocked due to content filtering by the network administrator"*

Since I'm at home I'd like to access these blocked sites directly, not over the VPN (since that would waste my workplace bandwidth for nothing, in addition to giving the place I work the places I'm browsing), but the same OpenDNS messages appear. (I'm of course trying to do this over my local Firefox, not over the RDP window at my workplace)

Under the VPN's IPv4 advanced properties I unchecked the "Use default gateway on remote network" and had to add a DNS suffix for the connection (not doing this last thing doesn't seem to change anything, only that I cannot connect to my work desktop via RDP).

I also tried setting google's DNS as primary alternative and my workplace's DNS as secondary, but the problem persists.

Why are my local requests being blocked by my workplace DNS? Shouldn't only traffic not resolved by my primary DNS be routed over the secondary one?

* I'm translating this, english version will probably be slightly different.

Edit: Adding diff between route print when connected to the VPN......

When connected it adds the following:

[route print](https://i.stack.imgur.com/p5IR1.png)

Comment: What's the vpn software you are using? You should be able to do what you are trying to do. It's usually a setting like "use vpn gateway for local addresses".

Comment: I'm using Windows VPN, no special software. There is a checkbox (under IPv4 advanced settings) which states "Use default gateway on remote network" which isn't checked.

Comment: If you are using Windows executing "route print" on the Command Prompt will display your routing table. For Linux the command will be "route -n". Does it show more than one route with 0.0.0.0 when you are connected to the vpn?

Comment: In both cases I've got more than 0.0.0.0. When connected to the VPN it adds some others (I'll edit the question to add the diff)